# Rails iframe tag not filling entire page at 100%

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, iframe

I'm embedding google maps into my website and I want the map to be full screen. I have the following iframe code, but you can see in the screen capture it isn't filling the entire screen. I'm using Ruby on Rails so I'm betting it's some sort of rails default CSS that is causing it?

```
<iframe
  height="100%"
  width="100%"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="<%= full_loc %>" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

[image]

The entire view code looks like this (it's very raw at this point lol):

```
<% full_loc = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyAC6wrz55kNEjlpa3g4ssAw9T4NdSa2mbM
  &q=" + @homes.location %>


<iframe
  height="100%"
  width="100%"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="<%= full_loc %>" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>

<%= form_tag(homes_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Posts" %>
<%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely that the `iframe`'s parents do not have a height set.

Please try adding `height: 100%;` for each parent of the `iframe`.

`html, body { height: 100%; }`

Comment: there are no parent tags. that's the thing with Rails, each view file is embedded into some other default view file. I think? I mean, it must? I have updated the post with the entire view code.

Comment: The views will generate HTML, and I'm referring to HTML parents of the `iframe`.  For example, the `html` and `body` tags are parents.  Try adding the following CSS rule: `html, body {height: 100%;}`

Comment: that did it, however there is still a border around the left top and right side even though I have `frameborder="0"`. any ideas? **EDIT** other answer solved this issue

Comment: You need to use `frameBorder="0"` with a capital B.  You can remove the `iframe`'s style.  However, if you were to use it, use `style="border: none;"`

Answer (score 1):

I think the space around the map is the default padding and margin.
Add:

```
 *{
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
  }
```

This sets the default values for each DOM element. It is not recommended to use the * selector. If you know which elements require `padding: 0;` and `margin: 0;` apply the CSS-Rule only to those.